# Adding enemies to a pygame platformer

Tags: python, pygame, scroller

I'm new to pygame and trying to make a platformer game that's based on this tutorial: http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=platform_scroller.py

I can't quite figure out how to add moving enemies, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Moving enemies would be something of a combination of how the `Player` and `Platform` objects work in the example to which you linked:

1. The enemy class would be a subclass of `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, similar to both aforementioned objects.
2. They would have to implement an `update()` method, similar to `Player`, to define how they move on each frame. Look at `Player.update()` for guidance; basically, move the `Enemy`'s `rect` in some way.
3. Instances of the enemy class should be added to a level's `enemy_list` object (which already exists in the example code), which means they would be updated and drawn on every frame. This is similar to how `Level_0x` constructors add `Platform` instances to the level's `platform_list` variable.

In short, that would look something like:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set the size, look, initial position, etc. of an enemy here...
        pass

    def update(self):
        # Define how the enemy moves on each frame here...
        pass

class Level_01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player):
        # platform code already in example goes here...

        # Add two enemies to the level
        self.enemy_list.add(Enemy())
        self.enemy_list.add(Enemy())
```